# React Native File chooser

Tags: file, react-native

Here's the trouble: I have searched high and low and I cannot for the life of me find how to show a file selector dialog in React Native. The closest thing is an image selector (3rd party component), but it's a specialized interface that won't let me pick arbitrary files from Android's filesystem.
Someone knows, how i can choose file?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this package [react-native-file-picker](https://github.com/Lichwa/react-native-file-picker%20'react-native-file-picker')

1. install the package from github

   npm install https://github.com/Lichwa/react-native-file-picker --save
2. then link it:

   rnpm link react-native-file-picker
3. import the package

   var FilePickerManager = require('NativeModules').FilePickerManager;
4. then use it like so:

   ```
   const options = {
       title: 'File Picker',
       chooseFileButtonTitle: 'Choose File...'
   };

   FilePickerManager.showFilePicker(options, (response) => {
       console.log('Response = ', response);

       if (response.didCancel) {
           console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
       }
       else if (response.error) {
           console.log('ImagePickerManager Error: ', response.error);
       }
       else if (response.customButton) {
           console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
       }
       else {
           this.setState({
               file: response
           });
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Update: that package will work only with react native 0.24 and is not mantained anymore. Use this fork: https://github.com/luisfuertes/react-native-file-picker

Comment: `react-native-file-picker` seems not work for files beside images and `react-native-image-picker` it's only for images... so... still looking for something which work for any kind of file.